# geom_point and geom_line not showing even after specifying group =1

Tags: r, ggplot2

The df looks like this:

(Year is 'character' type and mean is double )

| Year | mean |
| --- | --- |
| 11-12 | 0.3625971 |
| 13 | 0.3584357 |
| 14-15 | 0.3667632 |
| 16-17 | 0.3039611 |
| 18-19 | 0.3169676 |
| 21 | 0.2649566 |

Reproducible example (dput):

```
    structure(list(Year = c("11-12", "13", "14-15", "16-17", "18-19", "21"), mean = c(0.362597098050711, 0.358435740662268, 0.36676321506155, 0.303961136023916, 0.316967585260268, 0.264956571150256)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The code:

```html
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = mean, group = 1)) +
    geom_line()
```

The plot:

[image]

Comment: Possibly a typo: change `geom_point` for `geom_line`. Also it is preferable if you paste your data in the  question with the output of `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: Neither geom_point and geom_line works. Strangly though ggpubr::ggline worked. @Peter

Comment: Thanks for introducing dput! I included a reproducible example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue now: the points are plotted in white, so they cannot be seen.

[image]

The reason is that I once set the theme using `theme_set(dark_theme_gray())`, a theme from the ggdark library, where the points are in white. It's possible that the color of the points was preserved even after I changed the theme to theme_classic() using `theme_set(theme_classic())`

To fix this, run this:
`theme_set(invert_geom_defaults())` before setting a new theme.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine with ggplot

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- tribble(
~Year, ~mean,
"11-12",    0.3625971,
"13",   0.3584357,
"14-15",    0.3667632,
"16-17",    0.3039611,
"18-19",    0.3169676,
"21",   0.2649566)


ggplot(df1, aes(Year, mean))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(Year, mean, group = 1))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>